# fabricjs export to base 64(embedded png, jpeg, or svg and so on...)

Tags: java, angularjs, user-interface, canvas, fabricjs

I have fabricjs with image, which loadded by

`$scope.fabric.addImage(url)`

this url value ex) /image/image1.emf or /image/image2.svg, or /image/image3.png
...

but i need to export to json. 
now i'm using tojson Function `$scope.fabric.getSVGJSON()`
but this result json mapping src.

```
result 

    {"object":[{"type":"image", 
    ...... 
    "src":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/image/image1.emf"
    ..... and so on

    ## but i want it base64 like this ##
    {"object":[{"type":"image", 
    ...... 
    "src":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...."
    ..... and so on
```

please help me.